# Does saving all classes is same DLL makes sense?

Tags: dll

My program got about 5 classes that need each other to work. But my develop team may want to update something later, and i am asking you if it does make sense to load them by .dll instead of saving directly inside the executable. This is because if we want to change anything we may need to rebuild the executable again, wich is not good!

Comment: So you'll have to rebuild the DLL instead.  Whether you have to copy one file or the other makes no conceivable difference.  A slight advantage of having only one executable file is that you can never copy the wrong one :)

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for the tip